# .each not iterating over nested arrays

Tags: ruby, each

For some reason, this is not iterating over the collection. Throwing a pry in there shows that only the first index is getting looked at. `[0,1,2]` I'm sure I'm just tired and it's something small, but I'm drawing a black here,

```
WIN_COMBINATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
]

def won?(board)
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.each do |combo|
    if board[combo[0]] != " " && board[combo[0]] == board[combo[1]] && board[combo[0]] == board[combo[2]]
      return combo
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What param do you pass into your `won?` method?

Comment: @MarekLipka it's an array. `board = ["O", "O", " ", "X", "X", "X", " ", " ", " "]` in the test is where it's getting passed in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def won?(board)
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.any? do |combo|
    board[combo[0]] != " " &&
      board[combo[0]] == board[combo[1]] &&
      board[combo[0]] == board[combo[2]]
  end
end
```

or, even more succinct with [`Array#values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-values_at):

```
def won?(board)
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.any? do |combo|
    [%w|X| * 3, %w|O| * 3].include? board.values_at(*combo)
  end
end
```

Comment: @mike-heft In your actual code you should use this. This is more idiomatic ruby

Comment: ...or `arr =  board.values_at(*combo).uniq; arr.size == 1 && arr.first != ' '`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you might want to check the previous version of this answer :)

Comment: Ah, yes. I prefer your previous revision. Adding a variable and a second statement to remove the `select` clause is imo a [wash](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=it%27s%20a%20wash), but mainly, I think the earlier one reads better.

Comment: You can make your second version even more succinct: `def won?(board) false end` :-P

Comment: It's still wrong, now it returns `true` too often. I suggest you use a checker like I used in my answer.

Comment: @StefanPochmann indeed; fixed to leave all your checkers different.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that you return from your method on the first iteration.
Inside your iteration you always return after the first step. Just put the return false statement after your iteration and it will work.

Comment: Yup that was it. Was just coming back to answer Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Just three more solutions along with test code checking them against each other:

```
def won1?(board)
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.any? do |i, j, k|
    board[i] != " " && board[i] == board[j] && board[i] == board[k]
  end
end

def won2?(board)
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.any? do |combo|
    a, b = board.values_at(*combo).minmax; a != " " && a == b
  end
end

def won3?(board)
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.any? do |combo|
    [["X"], ["O"]].member?(board.values_at(*combo).uniq)
  end
end

WIN_COMBINATIONS = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
]

a = ["O", "X", " "]
a.product(*([a] * 8)).each { |board|
  w1 = won1?(board)
  w2 = won2?(board)
  w3 = won3?(board)
  p [w1, w2, w3, board] if w2 != w1 || w3 != w1
}
```

Comment: Another: `WIN_COMBINATIONS.any? {|combo| ["X", "O"].one? {|token| combo.all? {|i| board[i] == token}}`